# How to add sort to Pageable of JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to findAll `Product` which have `@ManyToMany` relationship with `kinds`

```java
  @ManyToMany
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
  @JoinTable(name = "rel_product__kind", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "kind_id"))
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "products" }, allowSetters = true)
  private Set<Kind> kinds = new HashSet<>();
```

This is my rest

```java
  @GetMapping("/products")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(ProductCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Products by criteria: {}", criteria);
    Page<Long> page = productQueryService.findIdsByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
    List<Product> list = productRepository.findAll(page.getContent());
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(list);
  }
```

```java
  @Query(
    value = "select product.id from Product product order by product.id",
    countQuery = "select count(product.id) from Product product"
  )
  Page<Long> getProductIds(Specification<Product> specification, Pageable pageable);

  @Query(value = "select distinct product from Product product left join fetch product.kinds where product.id in (:listProducts) order by product.id",
    countQuery = "select count(distinct product) from Product product")
  List<Product> findAll(@Param("listProducts") List<Long> listProducts);
```

Problem is my rest is work with pagination but I tried to add sort into request param

```
http://localhost:9000/api/products?page=0&size=20&sort=createAt,desc
```

My result still like

```
http://localhost:9000/api/products?page=0&size=20&sort=createAt,asc
```

Update:
`pagable` object

```
Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: createAt: DESC]
```

```
2021-09-01 18:48:56.955 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.web.rest.ProductResource     : Enter: getAllProducts() with argument[s] = [ProductCriteria{}, Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: createAt: DESC]]
2021-09-01 18:48:56.958 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.web.rest.ProductResource     : REST request to get Products by criteria: ProductCriteria{}
2021-09-01 18:48:56.967 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.service.ProductQueryService  : Enter: findIdsByCriteria() with argument[s] = [ProductCriteria{}, Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: createAt: DESC]]
2021-09-01 18:48:56.971 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.service.ProductQueryService  : find by criteria : ProductCriteria{}, page: {}
2021-09-01 18:48:56.986 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select product0_.id as col_0_0_ from product product0_ order by product0_.id, product0_.create_at desc limit ?
2021-09-01 18:48:57.002 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(product0_.id) as col_0_0_ from product product0_
2021-09-01 18:48:57.007 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.service.ProductQueryService  : Exit: findIdsByCriteria() with result = Page 1 of 3 containing java.lang.Long instances
2021-09-01 19:13:56.712  WARN 17872 --- [ari housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=25m14s292ms292�s300ns).
2021-09-01 19:13:56.740 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select distinct product0_.id as id1_11_0_, kind2_.id as id1_7_1_, product0_.category_id as category9_11_0_, product0_.create_at as create_a2_11_0_, product0_.description as descript3_11_0_, product0_.image_url as image_ur4_11_0_, product0_.inventory as inventor5_11_0_, product0_.name as name6_11_0_, product0_.player_id as player_10_11_0_, product0_.price as price7_11_0_, product0_.status as status8_11_0_, kind2_.create_at as create_a2_7_1_, kind2_.image_url as image_ur3_7_1_, kind2_.name as name4_7_1_, kinds1_.product_id as product_1_14_0__, kinds1_.kind_id as kind_id2_14_0__ from product product0_ left outer join rel_product__kind kinds1_ on product0_.id=kinds1_.product_id left outer join kind kind2_ on kinds1_.kind_id=kind2_.id where product0_.id in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?) order by product0_.id
2021-09-01 19:13:56.795 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select category0_.id as id1_1_0_, category0_.create_at as create_a2_1_0_, category0_.image_url as image_ur3_1_0_, category0_.name as name4_1_0_ from category category0_ where category0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.858 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select position0_.id as id1_10_0_, position0_.create_at as create_a2_10_0_, position0_.name as name3_10_0_ from position position0_ where position0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.868 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select sport0_.id as id1_15_0_, sport0_.create_at as create_a2_15_0_, sport0_.image_url as image_ur3_15_0_, sport0_.name as name4_15_0_ from sport sport0_ where sport0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.887 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select position0_.id as id1_10_0_, position0_.create_at as create_a2_10_0_, position0_.name as name3_10_0_ from position position0_ where position0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.894 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select team0_.id as id1_16_0_, team0_.create_at as create_a2_16_0_, team0_.image_url as image_ur3_16_0_, team0_.name as name4_16_0_, team0_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_0_, sport1_.id as id1_15_1_, sport1_.create_at as create_a2_15_1_, sport1_.image_url as image_ur3_15_1_, sport1_.name as name4_15_1_ from team team0_ left outer join sport sport1_ on team0_.sport_id=sport1_.id where team0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.904 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select player0_.id as id1_9_0_, player0_.create_at as create_a2_9_0_, player0_.image_url as image_ur3_9_0_, player0_.name as name4_9_0_, player0_.position_id as position5_9_0_, player0_.team_id as team_id6_9_0_, position1_.id as id1_10_1_, position1_.create_at as create_a2_10_1_, position1_.name as name3_10_1_, team2_.id as id1_16_2_, team2_.create_at as create_a2_16_2_, team2_.image_url as image_ur3_16_2_, team2_.name as name4_16_2_, team2_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_2_, sport3_.id as id1_15_3_, sport3_.create_at as create_a2_15_3_, sport3_.image_url as image_ur3_15_3_, sport3_.name as name4_15_3_ from player player0_ inner join position position1_ on player0_.position_id=position1_.id inner join team team2_ on player0_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join sport sport3_ on team2_.sport_id=sport3_.id where player0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.921 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select team0_.id as id1_16_0_, team0_.create_at as create_a2_16_0_, team0_.image_url as image_ur3_16_0_, team0_.name as name4_16_0_, team0_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_0_, sport1_.id as id1_15_1_, sport1_.create_at as create_a2_15_1_, sport1_.image_url as image_ur3_15_1_, sport1_.name as name4_15_1_ from team team0_ left outer join sport sport1_ on team0_.sport_id=sport1_.id where team0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.932 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select position0_.id as id1_10_0_, position0_.create_at as create_a2_10_0_, position0_.name as name3_10_0_ from position position0_ where position0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.946 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select player0_.id as id1_9_0_, player0_.create_at as create_a2_9_0_, player0_.image_url as image_ur3_9_0_, player0_.name as name4_9_0_, player0_.position_id as position5_9_0_, player0_.team_id as team_id6_9_0_, position1_.id as id1_10_1_, position1_.create_at as create_a2_10_1_, position1_.name as name3_10_1_, team2_.id as id1_16_2_, team2_.create_at as create_a2_16_2_, team2_.image_url as image_ur3_16_2_, team2_.name as name4_16_2_, team2_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_2_, sport3_.id as id1_15_3_, sport3_.create_at as create_a2_15_3_, sport3_.image_url as image_ur3_15_3_, sport3_.name as name4_15_3_ from player player0_ inner join position position1_ on player0_.position_id=position1_.id inner join team team2_ on player0_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join sport sport3_ on team2_.sport_id=sport3_.id where player0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.956 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select team0_.id as id1_16_0_, team0_.create_at as create_a2_16_0_, team0_.image_url as image_ur3_16_0_, team0_.name as name4_16_0_, team0_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_0_, sport1_.id as id1_15_1_, sport1_.create_at as create_a2_15_1_, sport1_.image_url as image_ur3_15_1_, sport1_.name as name4_15_1_ from team team0_ left outer join sport sport1_ on team0_.sport_id=sport1_.id where team0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.965 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select team0_.id as id1_16_0_, team0_.create_at as create_a2_16_0_, team0_.image_url as image_ur3_16_0_, team0_.name as name4_16_0_, team0_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_0_, sport1_.id as id1_15_1_, sport1_.create_at as create_a2_15_1_, sport1_.image_url as image_ur3_15_1_, sport1_.name as name4_15_1_ from team team0_ left outer join sport sport1_ on team0_.sport_id=sport1_.id where team0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.975 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select player0_.id as id1_9_0_, player0_.create_at as create_a2_9_0_, player0_.image_url as image_ur3_9_0_, player0_.name as name4_9_0_, player0_.position_id as position5_9_0_, player0_.team_id as team_id6_9_0_, position1_.id as id1_10_1_, position1_.create_at as create_a2_10_1_, position1_.name as name3_10_1_, team2_.id as id1_16_2_, team2_.create_at as create_a2_16_2_, team2_.image_url as image_ur3_16_2_, team2_.name as name4_16_2_, team2_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_2_, sport3_.id as id1_15_3_, sport3_.create_at as create_a2_15_3_, sport3_.image_url as image_ur3_15_3_, sport3_.name as name4_15_3_ from player player0_ inner join position position1_ on player0_.position_id=position1_.id inner join team team2_ on player0_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join sport sport3_ on team2_.sport_id=sport3_.id where player0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:56.985 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select player0_.id as id1_9_0_, player0_.create_at as create_a2_9_0_, player0_.image_url as image_ur3_9_0_, player0_.name as name4_9_0_, player0_.position_id as position5_9_0_, player0_.team_id as team_id6_9_0_, position1_.id as id1_10_1_, position1_.create_at as create_a2_10_1_, position1_.name as name3_10_1_, team2_.id as id1_16_2_, team2_.create_at as create_a2_16_2_, team2_.image_url as image_ur3_16_2_, team2_.name as name4_16_2_, team2_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_2_, sport3_.id as id1_15_3_, sport3_.create_at as create_a2_15_3_, sport3_.image_url as image_ur3_15_3_, sport3_.name as name4_15_3_ from player player0_ inner join position position1_ on player0_.position_id=position1_.id inner join team team2_ on player0_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join sport sport3_ on team2_.sport_id=sport3_.id where player0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:57.001 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select position0_.id as id1_10_0_, position0_.create_at as create_a2_10_0_, position0_.name as name3_10_0_ from position position0_ where position0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:57.017 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select team0_.id as id1_16_0_, team0_.create_at as create_a2_16_0_, team0_.image_url as image_ur3_16_0_, team0_.name as name4_16_0_, team0_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_0_, sport1_.id as id1_15_1_, sport1_.create_at as create_a2_15_1_, sport1_.image_url as image_ur3_15_1_, sport1_.name as name4_15_1_ from team team0_ left outer join sport sport1_ on team0_.sport_id=sport1_.id where team0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:57.039 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select player0_.id as id1_9_0_, player0_.create_at as create_a2_9_0_, player0_.image_url as image_ur3_9_0_, player0_.name as name4_9_0_, player0_.position_id as position5_9_0_, player0_.team_id as team_id6_9_0_, position1_.id as id1_10_1_, position1_.create_at as create_a2_10_1_, position1_.name as name3_10_1_, team2_.id as id1_16_2_, team2_.create_at as create_a2_16_2_, team2_.image_url as image_ur3_16_2_, team2_.name as name4_16_2_, team2_.sport_id as sport_id5_16_2_, sport3_.id as id1_15_3_, sport3_.create_at as create_a2_15_3_, sport3_.image_url as image_ur3_15_3_, sport3_.name as name4_15_3_ from player player0_ inner join position position1_ on player0_.position_id=position1_.id inner join team team2_ on player0_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join sport sport3_ on team2_.sport_id=sport3_.id where player0_.id=?
2021-09-01 19:13:57.081 DEBUG 17872 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] com.na.shop.web.rest.ProductResource     : Exit: getAllProducts() with result = <200 OK OK,[Product{id=1, name='Ja Morant 2020-21 Lights Camera Action Holo #30', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629138778/Card%20images/Ja-Morant_cusr8r.jpg', price=155000.0, description='', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=2, name='Trae Young NBA Hoops - Slam #6', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629138850/Card%20images/Trae-Young_1_l0hikb.jpg', price=90000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=3, name='Patrick Williams Class of 2020 #1', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139003/Card%20images/Patrick-Williams_h8dmdw.jpg', price=20000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=4, name='James Wiseman Rise N Shine #RNS-JWS', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139205/Card%20images/James-Wiseman_cpk8n7.jpg', price=230000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=5, name='Kyrie Irving NBA Hoops Blue #33', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139424/Card%20images/Kyrie-Irving_wl0gi8.jpg', price=80000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=6, name='Lonnie Walker IV Purple #167', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139503/Card%20images/Lonnie-Walker-IV_ocwyvf.jpg', price=85000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-15T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=7, name='James Harden Past & Present #22', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139546/Card%20images/James-Harden_1_mepdpk.jpg', price=25000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=8, name='Russell Westbrook Lights Camera Action #13', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139621/Card%20images/Russell-Westbrook_aci4x4.jpg', price=18000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=9, name='Donovan Mitchell Frequent Flyers #8', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629139730/Card%20images/Donovan-Mitchell_i7em2r.jpg', price=15000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=13, name='Patrick McCaw Rookies Panini Threads 2016-17', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629201086/Card%20images/Rookies---Patrick-McCaw_1_dciwge.jpg', price=10000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=14, name='Full set 100 th? Donruss Soccer 2015 series #1-100', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629202439/233791064_913810479207250_1370156577829834824_n_zskvbm.jpg', price=750000.0, description='Tr?n b? 100 th? c?a seri Donruss 2015 https://www.cardboardconnection.com/2015-donruss-soccer-cards', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=15, name='Kevin Love 2016-17 Panini Prestige Gold Crack #99', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629256310/Card%20images/235454952_1065206690963165_8743925674903993617_n_mxfbnd.jpg', price=95000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-18T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=16, name='Blake Griffin 2018-19 Panini Certified - Gold Team #GT-12', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629256816/Card%20images/229540450_819199635423012_2946869088537211117_n_igtot9.jpg', price=25000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-18T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=17, name='Blake Griffin 2017-18 Panini Essentials #22', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629691579/Card%20images/DADD4ABA-ED11-4342-A445-3E562833CB88_z9wpxx.jpg', price=23000.0, description='null', inventory=2, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-16T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=18, name='Andre Drummond Blue #22', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629374763/Card%20images/D802F163-FB04-4872-A907-5EC3F8593F2C_bwcj1m.jpg', price=20000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-19T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=19, name='Reggie Jackson 2017-18 Panini Opulence Series 24/79', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629376044/Card%20images/74A9FC8D-5009-40D2-91D2-A3A970A4D93D_vxancy.jpg', price=75000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-19T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=20, name='Ben Simmons 2020-21 Panini NBA Hoops - Vanity Plates #20', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629376487/Card%20images/39B9488F-B386-442E-AC37-CCA923631B62_qjzbu8.jpg', price=20000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-19T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=21, name='Kawhi Leonard 2020-21 Panini NBA Hoops - Vanity Plates #4', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629377052/Card%20images/B4C5BE94-B0D7-46CF-9E0C-735EAB26073B_qxf7km.jpg', price=20000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-17T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=22, name='Jordan Bell 2017-18 Panini Prestige - Rookie Class #24', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629377252/Card%20images/9C277E7A-CFFF-43B4-9DE4-1FA61F5B65D2_zlalbg.jpg', price=18000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-19T00:00:00Z'}, Product{id=23, name='Jacob Evans III 2018-19 Panini NBA Hoops #279', imageUrl='https://res.cloudinary.com/lcm-system-fpt/image/upload/v1629378132/Card%20images/12C89572-166E-4EB9-9290-D1136E3026DE_bw4x7k.jpg', price=10000.0, description='null', inventory=1, status='AVAILABLE', createAt='2021-08-17T00:00:00Z'}],[X-Total-Count:"55", Link:"<http://localhost:9000/api/products?sort=createAt%2Cdesc&page=1&size=20>; rel="next",<http://localhost:9000/api/products?sort=createAt%2Cdesc&page=2&size=20>; rel="last",<http://localhost:9000/api/products?sort=createAt%2Cdesc&page=0&size=20>; rel="first""]>
```

Or the sort is not working, it just fetch from top to bottom in `product` table
What is wrong?

Comment: Can you enable sql log and show the sql ? Also can you print the pageable object in the controller ?

Comment: I am seeing the sql `select product0_.id as col_0_0_ from product product0_ order by product0_.id, product0_.create_at desc limit ?` . It has order by and desc in it . In which query you want to add sorting ?

Comment: @Shawrup that is my problem, the syntax is find but the result is not as expected. My expected is sort product list by newest to oldest

Comment: You are applying sorting while fetching the id list and then you are using in query to get the results. The in query does not garantee the order of the ids in the results. You need to add sorting to findAll methods. Better yet add specification and sorting in the findAll , so you can skip the first query.

Comment: @Shawrup I'm getting problem with eager relationship, I can't easily use findAll()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236653/discussion-between-dungreact-and-shawrup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I don't think it's the best but it can help me right now. It's disable `hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch`